# Possible to run Javascript from address bar (bookmarklet) within Google Chrome's settings panel?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarklet

I would like to make a bookmarklet to open google chrome's settings panel and clear my cache with a single click.

For a while now, Ive had a bookmark that opens chrome's settings panel with the 'clear cache' setting already selected. After clicking the bookmark (normally opening it in a new tab) I have to then opent the tab and submit the form. However, when developing this is a task I have to do quite often and these several repeated steps just seem unnecessary.

This link opens the page to clear one's cache (obviously for Chrome users only): chrome://chrome/settings/clearBrowserData#cache

I recently discovered bookmarklets and thought it would be a good way to accomplish the task of clearing my cache with a single click. However, I've discovered that putting even a basic javascript sample in the address bar when on the settings page (linked above) fails to work.

For example, this works in the address bar on any given page, but not from the chrome settings page:

```
javascript:alert('hello stackoverflow');
```

Is there a way to execute javascript from the chrome settings page? Are there other options? Im looking for any route to achieve this goal and would love to learn something along the way, even if it means doing some evil. :)

Comment: Chrome's security policy is strict. No extensions (or external JS, apparently) can run on `chrome://` pages.

Comment: @Blender: Appreciated. I'd still be curious if there exists a way to circumvent their blocks even if it breaks with their policies.

Answer (score 7):

add a bookmark:

```
javascript:document.write('<form onsubmit="window.open(\'javascript:\'+js_line.value, \'target\');return false;">javascript:<input type=text name=js_line style="width:90%;"/></form><iframe src="" name="target" style="width:100%;height:90%;"/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want might not be fully possible through a bookmarklet, but it's certainly possible with a Chrome App. There is an app [Clear Cache](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn/) already. I find it pretty useful.