# Is it possible to pass HTTP headers in the URL itself?

Tags: http, url, http-headers, postman

For example: if i wanted to pass `Content-Type` as `application/json` in the url itself, how would I do that?

I do know about Postman, but have not used it much. I was wondering if I could just do what I need from chrome itself, without needing to use POSTMAN.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't. HTTP standard has no way to do that.

But you can run JS with ajax request with you headers from address bar via bookmarklets mechanism.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet

[Possible to run Javascript from address bar (bookmarklet) within Google Chrome's settings panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076309/possible-to-run-javascript-from-address-bar-bookmarklet-within-google-chromes)